# Problems deleting records from a Shapefile using Editor() class in pyShp

Tags: python, shapefile, pyshp

I'm using pyShp to add three polygons in a new shapefile. I added the geometry and the records (attributes). So far no problem.

Later, I wanted to use the Editor() class to delete one of the three polygons. If I try to delete the last one 'P3', it works fine.

The problem appears when I try to delete any other of the polygons. For instance, if I delete the first one, the shape disappear but its attributes remain so the 'P2' polygon inherit them. The record that is deleted is the last one (originally linked to 'P3').

```
import shapefile
w = shapefile.Writer(shapefile.POLYGONZ)
print(w.shapeType)
w.poly(parts=[[[0,0],[5,0],[5,5],[0,5]]])
w.poly(parts=[[[10,0],[15,0],[15,10],[10,5]]])
w.poly(parts=[[[5,10],[10,10],[10,15],[5,15]]])

w.field('NAME', 'C',40)
w.record('P1')
w.record('P2')
w.record('P3')
w.save("polygons")

edit = shapefile.Editor("polygons")
edit.delete(0)
edit.save("polygonDeleted")
```

I know I could select the two shapes that I want to keep and write them in a new shapefile but I'd like to understand why the Editor() class doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of pyshp removed the Editor() class so is no longer avalaible.